# Is it possible to change a value and the scale size, position, or rotation of an object can be affected by that value?

Tags: camera

Im trying to create my own camera by adding a ruler and pull downs and have gotten it to work well.

[image: Camera Ruler & Pull Down View]

The only issue is that when I change the "Focal Length" it does not match up to the the camera any more.

[image: Changing the Cameras Focal Length]

Is there any way to make the size & position change with the "Focal Length"?